# element at index in a circular linked list

Tags: java

I was reading about circular linked lists. Here is a code which I do not understand how it works.

```
public int elementAt(int index){
        if(index>size){
            return -1;
        }
        Node n = head;
        while(index-1!=0){ // this line is unclear for me
            n=n.next;
            index--;
        }
        return n.data;
    }
```

I would write the same code but in this way :

```
public int elementAt(int index){
        if(index>size){
            return -1;
        }
        Node n = head;
        while(n.size != index){ // here is my change in the code
            n=n.next;
        }
        return n.data;
    }
```

Here is the whole code : http://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/circular-linked-list-complete-implementation/

Am I doing right in the second code  ?

Thanks

Comment: Why not check it yourself / use a debugger?

Comment: what would `n.size` be?

Comment: here is the whole code http://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/circular-linked-list-complete-implementation/ thanks

Comment: update the link in question too.

Comment: Well, there is no `n.size`. I suggest you try to compile and run your code.

Comment: There is no field `Node.size` in the link you posted, so your version is invalid.

Comment: @Thomas How can I do such  field `Node.size`

Comment: You'd create it but it probably wouldn't make much sense since the size of a node means a different thing than the size of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is just doing a count. You can do it in various way. I assume that the size is the size of your LinkedList. In that case your code is wrong. you can do like following

```
public int elementAt(int index){
        if(index>size){
            return -1;
        }
        Node n = head;
        int i = 0; // zero-indexing
        while(i++ != index){ // you can increment i at the end too
            n=n.next;
        }
        return n.data;
    }
```

FIrst code is also counting, but instead of using another variable it used the existing one

Comment: thank you very much ,, I do understand ,, God bless you  :)

Answer (score 1):

The example code uses a 1-based index: 1, 2, 3, ..., size. Which is strange in computer science, where one would expect: 0, .. , size-1.

Unfortunately `size` is a property of the entire list, not a single Node in the list. So their solution is fine.

Though when index <= 0 then nice things happen.

---

For a real *circular* list the Node has a `previous` field. And the last node is linked both ways to the first node.

In that case you can walk in both directions, following `next` or `previous`.
Then when index < size / 2 one would by `next` forwards to the index, or else go back by `previous` for about (size - index) steps. In order to take the least number of steps.

Comment: "nice things" indeed ;)

Answer (score 0):

The line which you do not understand is just counting "index" positions fordward, and it is starting at head. So the method is giving you back the element "index -1" positions from the head element
Other assumption is that the head element is at 1